# Sharepoint File Uploading - Limit of file size

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sharepoint-2013, filesize, csom

Can anyone tell me what is the file limit when uploading a file through code using client object model (javascript) Sharepoint 2013.

Thanks

Comment: Each Web Application By default have 50MB for one time attachment to be uploaded. You can modify it from:

Central Admin -> Manage Application -> Select your web application -> General Setting -> Set Max Upload Size

If file size is too large then you should also update executionTimeOut (Increase this time from IIS Setting) value and ConnectionTimeout (Update this time from web application web.config file) value.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

In Central Admin, the allowed file size is 10MB.
I am using javascript code to upload a file into my document library through UI.
Whenever I try to upload a file > 2MB, its not allowing me.

Throws the following error: 

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

"The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes."

Please suggest.